# ¿Cómo agregar información a un fichero con funciones?

Tags: python, funciones, variables-globales, archivo

Tengo un problema , quisiera que la función `calc()` recibiera los datos recibidos por la función `agrega()` y realizara todos los cálculos planteados;pero por algún motivo al llegar a los datos nuevos sólo lee un salto de línea ('\n') y salta el error `list index out of range` dado que, claramente no hay nada en esa posición; adjunto el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import os   
new=''
temp=0
pre=0
tempo=0
hume=0
people=0
data=''
def existe():
    exist=os.path.isfile('Datos.txt')
    if exist== False: 
        fichero=open('Datos.txt',w)
        fichero.close()  
def calc():
    tpeo=0
    maxipeo=0
    count=0
    ttemp=0
    mtemp=0

    fichero=open('Datos.txt', 'r') 
    fichero.readline()

    for i in fichero:
        data=i.split(';')
        hora=data[0]
        minu=data[1]
        pre=data[2]
        temp=float(data[3])
        hume=float(data[4])
        people=int(data[5])
        tpeo+=people
        if people>maxipeo:
            maxipeo=people
            tempo=hora+':'+minu
        if count==0:
            minitemp=temp 
        if temp<minitemp: 
            minitemp=temp
        ttemp+=temp
        count+=1
        mtemp=ttemp/count
        #hora en la que se ha registrado el mayor número de personas
        #hora asociada al mayor nro de personas 
    print('The values for the laboratory from 8:00 to 20:00')
    print('Pressure: ',pre)
    print('Temperature:',temp)
    print('Humidity:',hume)
    print('People in the lab:',people)
    print('Time:',tempo)
    print('Maximum number of people is: ',maxipeo)
    print('The total temperature is: ',ttemp)
    print('The average temperature is: ',mtemp)

    fichero.close()

def agrega():
    global new 
    add=input('Do you want to add something to the fichero y:yes n:no ')

    if add.lower()=='y':
        many=str(input('How many days do you want to add?--> '))
        for i in range(int(many)):
            fichero=open('Datos.txt','a')
            new=input(str('Insert data separated by ";" '))
            fichero.write(new)
            fichero.close()
        return new 

    else:
        calc()
        print('Bye')
existe() 
agrega() 
calc()
```

Comment: Deberias colocar en las etiquetas, el lenguaje y no esas palabras clave que no sirven para buscar en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar este tipo de error, puedes aplicar una condición `if` a cada línea en cuanto entras al ciclo `for` de `fichero`, para descartar las líneas no deseadas (p.e. que solo contienen '\n').

Ejemplo:

```
...
...
fichero=open('Datos.txt', 'r') 
fichero.readline()

for i in fichero:
    if i != '\n':
       data=i.split(';')
       ...
       ...
```

Otra alternativa, es crear una función que limpie tu fichero de lineas o caracteres inconsistentes o indeseados, para transformar el fichero inicial, antes de ejecutar todo tu proceso.

Ejemplo ([tomado de este sitio](https://www.altaruru.com/python-eliminar-lineas-de-archivos-texto/)):

```
def deleteline(filein, fileout, slinea):
    # copia un archivo eliminando en la copia las lineas que coinciden con slinea
    fin = open(filein, "r")
    fout = open(fileout, "w")
    for linea in fin:
        if(slinea!=linea):
            fout.write(linea)
    fout.close()
    fin.close()
```

Espero que te sea útil y bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. No olvides pasarte por aquí: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)